# Does Matthew 4:4 imply that there is a difference between the spoken word of God, and the written word?

Tags: matthew, scripture

Matthew 4:4 states:

> Jesus answered, “It is written: ‘Man shall not live on bread alone, but on every word that comes from the mouth of God.”

Does "comes from the mouth of God" imply that the spoken word of God is different from the written word?

I clearly see that the spoken word is alive, while the written word, any written word, is subject to interpretation.

Isn't it the role of God's Spirit to help us understand and live the spoken word of God? If it were not for God's Spirit, there would be no understanding. The religious leaders at the time of Christ created mountains of power and held themselves at the highest positions of authority yet could not understand the written words of the prophets. They could recite their history but they could not understand its meaning.

Comment: All of the scripture was originally spoken by someone on earth, then recorded in writing. God spoke by a 'similitude', Numbers 12:8, (in private) to Moses (again, words spoken on earth) and he recorded it. It needs to be determined whether the Greek word means 'mouth' (precisely) or does it mean 'mouthpiece' ? Up-voted +1.

Comment: Understood. Regardless of how a word is defined, I have learned that the meaning of words is only truly understood by the originator. Words by themselves have limited meaning and the reader often has to interpret (best guess) to understand. The only way to understand long text is to understand how the words are used in context. What do they describe? Poetic prose often uses words and word segments to convey an emotional package for better understanding. I've recognized some of the prophets, as Isaiah, used poetic prose to convey a better picture to the reader. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The word of God is only truly understood by the Originator and he to whom God will reveal His word. Agreed.

Comment: Although it is true that the word of God is only truly understood by the Originator. However, there is only one Bible in hundred languages, hundred translations, numerous interpretation, that will continue to growth. Does it mean in time, people know God even worse? It can't be for it is against God's will. God in Jeremiah 31:31-34 talked about the new covenant. We no longer need anyone to teach us to know God, because, as Jesus revealed in John 14:26,  the Holy Spirit will teach us all things and remind us of everything He have said to us. I believe, have faith, and reward the understand.

Comment: The religious authorities too can claim they do it with God's spirit. Spoken word is same as written, both subject to interpretation, even the direct visions and dreams to a man.

Answer (score 2):

Verbatim reporting gives the exact words that were spoken. There is no need for anyone other than the speaker and the reporter to hear the voice of the speaker in order to take the written words as 100% accurate. The only difference is that those not present when the speaker spoke can still get to know the exact words originally spoken. A written record has the advantage of being printed, or electronically reproduced, going global, and lasting for centuries. As long as it is a verbatim report, and nobody comes along later to change the report, there is no effective difference, although (obviously) hearing God speak would be a powerfully unique experience, never to be forgotten.

The verse in question was Jesus rebutting his satanic tempter's suggestion that Jesus check the veracity of God having said to him that he was the Son of God. Interestingly, Satan must have heard God say that (at Jesus' baptism 40 days earlier) as well as John the Baptist. This gives proof to everyone else who never heard God's actual words on that occasion, that God really had said Jesus was his beloved Son (Mat. 3:17). Satan took those words as actual and Jesus knew they were the very words of God.

The context of Mat. 4:4 means that Jesus' point was not the contrast of bread with God's spoken words, but by Jesus quoting that ancient written phrase in Deuteronomy 8:3 he confirms that the purported words of God back then were accurately recorded, so that he could quote them with authority to expose Satan as a twister of God's written word. Likewise with the second temptation to throw himself down from the temple. Jesus again quoted accurately other parts in the ancient scriptures.

The point about living off every word from God applies to all who have never heard the voice of God themselves, but who have the meticulously recorded and copied ancient writings that are the very words of God. The Jewish scribes had the most astonishing methods of ensuring those manuscripts were copied faithfully down the centuries, to the day of Christ and beyond. The Holy Spirit gives the inspired word of God to be written down, likewise with the Christian Greek scriptures. Although some human error can creep in, the Holy Spirit has also given the divine preservation of scripture along with its inspiration. What we have received in the Received Text is just as much the work of the Holy Spirit as gaining his understanding when we read it in faith.

Yes, many people read the written word of God supposing that will give them life but, as Jesus said, those who read it but who refuse to come to him for life, will not gain life (John 5:39-40). That is because he is the Word of God. All who come to the Word of God will be given to understand the very words of God that give life eternal, as the Holy Spirit reads hearts and his work is to lift Christ up. The written word of God does that, from Genesis to Revelation.

***My answer is that*** **you cannot use Matthew 4:4 to imply that there is a difference between the spoken, and the written, word of God** because what God had spoken 40 days earlier had not yet been written down, then both Satan and Jesus took those words of God they had heard as true. God really had said Jesus was his Son. Matthew later reported the whole account accurately, for our benefit, with the additional confirmation from Jesus quoting Deuteronomy that those other words spoken by God back then were also still true.

The problem of interpretation you mention can only come later when individuals put their own meaning on to written words. But **the verse you ask about clearly shows that there was no effective difference** between what God had said (in Deuteronomy plus 40 days after Jesus' baptism) and Matthew's written report which we have to this very day.

Answer (score 0):

The פִי־יְהֹוָה "Mouth of YHVH" teaching quoted in [Matthew 4:4] simply recites the words of Moshe(משֶׁה):"Moses" from [Devarim/Deuteronomy 8:3].

"Man does not live by bread alone, but rather by whatever comes forth from the Mouth of YHVH - does man live." ( לֹא עַל־הַלֶּחֶם לְבַדּוֹ יִֽחְיֶה הָאָדָם כִּי עַל־כָּל־מוֹצָא פִֽי־יְהֹוָ֖ה יִֽחְיֶה הָֽאָדָם)

With angelic mediation, the פֶּה אֶל־פֶּה "mouth-to-mouth" discussions of YHVH to Moshe (Numbers 12:8) is synonymous in the phrase : " וַיְדַבֵּר יְהֹוָה אֶל־משֶׁ֥ה לֵּאמֹֽר " in [Exodus 6:10]. During his moments of Inspiration, Moshe always hears the מַלְאַךְ Malak 'Angel' of YHVH speaking - based on [Exodus 33:20].

The פִי־יְהֹוָה Mouth of YHVH was a Prophetic Preface **Koh-Amar YHVH (כֹּֽה־אָמַר יְהֹוָה) = So says YHVH**, misused to ensure inspirational guidance would be trusted. < See [Jeremiah 23:16].

Comment: I wish, with all of my heart, that I could read and understand Hebrew, old and new.

Answer (score 0):

We have the written word of God in the Bible, but do we still have a spoken word from Him? I once had a friend in Church who said he would only believe if God gave him a call. I didn't know how to answer at that time.

My answer now is "Yes", we do have spoken word from God, but it is not delivered via any device. Rather, He speaks directly in our ears, our hearts and minds.

In John 14:26, Jesus elaborate God's planning as described in Jeremiah 31:31-34, ***"But the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I have said to you."***

Everyone of us will encounter troubles in life. At times, we may be tempted to lie thinking the trouble will pass. Then a whisper in ears telling that Bible forbids lies. This is the conscience in ourselves, words from the Spirit.

In the Book of Revelation, Jesus wrote to the seven churches in Asia Minor, ending each letter with the phrase, ***"Whoever has ears, let them hear what the Spirit says to the churches"***. It is not necessary to learn Hebrew or Greek to understand the teachings of the Bible. Rather a good listening is more important,  able to hear the whisper of the Spirit louder and louder.

Most of us are not scholars who know the words in Bible precisely. Many teachings in Bible are plain to understand which is enough for the Holy Spirit to work effectively. In time, both our faith and knowledge will grow.

Answer (score 0):

The OP’s question uncovers a hidden riddle in the text. The answer is that the written word of God is the same as the spoken word. After all, how would we know of Jesus if not by reading the Gospels? Both are the bread from heaven; the difference lies in how we consume it. We cannot live on bread alone, that is, we cannot live by partaking only of the flesh. In other words, we cannot live by the letter of God's words alone, but by the Spirit. This is the Spirit of Christ that is shown by his example. If he had made bread from stone, he would have been able to feed the flesh, but in choosing not to do so, he showed us how to live by the spirit of humble and faithful obedience to the word of God.

> For truly I say to you, until heaven and earth pass away, not the
> smallest letter or stroke of a letter shall pass from the Law, until
> all is accomplished! - Mt 5:18 NASB